# Cannot specify a column width on data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I'm new here. I'm attempting to create a table in **ms sql** database using **mylittleadmin**. I've read and reread the code and can't seem to figure out why I am getting the following error:

"**Msg 2716, Level 16, State 1, Line number 1
Column, parameter, or variable #8: Cannot specify a column width on data type int.**"

The code is as follows...

```
CREATE TABLE surrogate(
Last_Name1 VarChar(255),
First_Name1 VarChar(255),
ID int,
Street_Address int,
City VarChar(255),
State_or_Province VarChar(255),
Country VarChar(255),
Zip_Code int(255),
Home_Phone int,
Mobile_Phone int,
Work_Phone int,
Email VarChar(255),
Last_Name2 VarChar(255),
First_Name2 VarChar(255),
ID int,
Street_Address2 int,
City2 VarChar(255),
State_or_Province2 VarChar(255),
Country2 VarChar(255),
Zip_Code2 int,
Home_Phone2 int,
Mobile_Phone2 int,
Work_Phone2 int,
Email2 VarChar(255),
Last_Name3 VarChar(255), 
First_Name3 VarChar(255),
ID int,
Street_Address3 int,
City3 VarChar(255),
State_or_Province3 VarChar(255),
Country3 VarChar (255),
Zip_Code3 int,
Home_Phone3 int,
Mobile_Phone3 int,
Work_Phone3 int,
Email3 VarChar(255))
```

Comment: you have 3 columns named 'ID'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its just a typo mistake. Guess you haven't seen it yet. This is the problem:

```
Zip_Code int(255),
```

Change it to

```
Zip_Code int,
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know how I missed it thanks form being patient with me!

Comment: @user3561122 Welcome. As Richard Inglis pointed out above, you also have 3 ID columns. This will still not create your table!!You will need to change the names of atleast 2 of the these 'ID' columns for your create script to run.